# How to export a raster data as CSV to asset in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have just started with GEE. I want to do SDM, as I wanted to do for a large area I choose GEE over R, but I feel SDM in R will be easier, so I want to export raster data from GEE for a very big area like full India, while exporting it get an error:

> Error: Image.sample: Computed value is too large. (Error code: 3)

What is wrong?

```
var DEM = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003")

var AOI = ee.Geometry.BBox(66.72524486860151,5.438315476908535,98.98110424360151,38.61474592164587);


//calculating slope, Aspect & Hillshade
var terrain = ee.Algorithms.Terrain(DEM); 

var table = terrain.sample({
   region: AOI,  // myRegion should be a geometry, the bounds of the city
  scale: 100,  // how far apart in meters the samples are (approximately; depends on projection)
  geometries: true,  // include the sampled points in export
});

Export.table.toAsset(table,'DEM_csv');
```

Comment: You are sampling the image at a scale of `100m` without specifying `numPixels`. That will give you a very large number of pixels to sample, which will fail. If you want to export all that data at `100m` scale, you are a lot better off exporting the actual image, instead of turning it into features and exporting them as a CSV.